# Mocking user input for TDD for React using Mocha, Chai and JSDom?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

I have a search bar that I want to test for user input. I am rendering the view with React and writing the tests using Chai, Mocha and JSDom.

Here are the simple tests I have written so far

```
 describe('Search', () => {
    it('renders a search bar', () => {
        const component = renderIntoDocument(
            <Search />
        );
        const search_bar = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(component, 'input-group');

        expect(search_bar.length).to.equal(1);
    });

    it('invokes a callback when the Add button is clicked', () => {
        let search_term;
        const clickHandler = (term) => search_term = term;

        const component = renderIntoDocument(
            <Search onClick={clickHandler}/>
        )

        const add_button = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'button');
        Simulate.click(add_button[0]);

        expect(search_term).to.equal('');
    });

    it('accepts user input from the search button and performs a regex check for invalid input', () => {
        let search_term;
        const clickHandler = (term) => search_term = term;

        const component = renderIntoDocument(
            <Search onClick={clickHandler} />
        );

        const add_button = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'button');
        const search_bar = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(component, 'input-group');

        Simulate.change(search_bar[0], {target: {value: 'FB'}});
        expect(search_bar[0].state.value).to.equal('FB');
    })
})
```

1) I want to test that the user inputs characters before hitting the Add button.

2) I want to test that the user does not input any numerals or special characters into the search term, the string needs to be only alphabets.

How do I simulate these tests?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have an answer after some debugging. But, it seems to be a little bit of a hack. 
Here is the component I am rendering into the DOM

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Search extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                value: ''
            }
        }

        handleChange(event){
            this.setState({value: event.target.value})
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className='input-group'>
                    <input ref='input' type='text' className='form-control' placeholder='Enter stock ticker' value={this.state.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <span className='input-group-btn'>
                        <button className='btn btn-primary' type='submit' 
                        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.state.value)}>
                            Add
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    Search.propTypes = {
        onClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    export default Search;
```

Here is the unit test to accept user input. Does not include validation

```
it('accepts user input from the search button', () => {
        let search_term;
        const clickHandler = (term) => search_term = term;

        const component = renderIntoDocument(
            <Search onClick={clickHandler} />
        );

        component.state.value = 'FB';

        expect(component.state.value).to.equal('FB');
    })
```

The reason I am not so sure about this is because I am explicitly setting component.state.value = 'FB' and then checking if it is, which it will be. But this is the closest I have gotten to validating that the value actually changes, because trying to run

```
Simulate.change(component, {state: {value: 'FB'}});
```

throws an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property
>   '__reactInternalInstance$gvviufwbzvqrhtud00vbo6r' of undefined

Trying the following according to the React docs (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#simulate)

```
it('accepts user input from the search button', () => {
    let search_term;
    const clickHandler = (term) => search_term = term;

    const component = renderIntoDocument(
        <Search onClick={clickHandler} />
    );
    const input = component.refs.input;
    input.value = 'FB';
    Simulate.change(input);
    expect(input.value).to.equal('FB');
    // component.state.value = 'FB';
    // expect(component.state.value).to.equal('FB');
})
```

returns an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

presumably because the state has to be set when the Simulate function is called, and the input ref only reads the state.

If anyone has any answers to these various errors, or even how exactly the Simulate functionality works (the docs aren't a great help), do share.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm going to add another answer because i'd still like answers to the questions about the Simulate object I raised in my previous answer.

The issue I was having had nothing to do with the test I was writing, but the fact that I had not bound this to the handleChange method inside the Search container.

Here is the updated constructor for the Search container

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
```

And here is the test that will now pass

```
it('accepts user input from the search button', () => {
        let search_term;
        const clickHandler = (term) => search_term = term;

        const component = renderIntoDocument(
            <Search onClick={clickHandler} />
        );
        const input = component.refs.input;
        input.value = 'FB';
        Simulate.change(component.refs.input);
        expect(input.value).to.equal('FB');
    })
```